# How to submit data from Web User Control

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a form that I put on the Web User Control, but "Submit" button is on the parent page.

The form contains user information. That same form displays for admins to edit a user and for the user to register and update profile.

I wanted to have the form in only 1 place to display in those 3 places.

The admin page will have a little more information on it, along with the "user info" control.

how can i reference items on the control page from the parent page?

am i doing this wrong?

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to do to tell you if you are doing it right or wrong :-)  Please elaborate, or post some code.

Answer (score 6):

You could make the control's elements (e.g. a contained `TextBox`) accessible through properties.

E.g.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public string MyText 
    {
        get { return MyTextBox.Text; }
        set { MyTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Then, access the properties from the page that contains the web user control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FindControl method and cast using CType. Here is an example...

```
    Dim objUserControl As UserControl = CType(Me.FindControl("IdOfUserControl"), UserControl)
    Dim strTextOfLabelInUserControl As String = CType(objUserControl.FindControl("IdOfLabelInUserControl"), Label).Text
```

or better yet...

```
    Dim strTextOfLabelInUserControl as String = CType(IdOfUserControl.FindControl("IdOfLabelInUserControl"), Label).Text
```

However, you may want to consider using Uwe Keim's approach to avoid the Overhead of casting and the FindControl methods.  His translated into VB .Net is this...

```
Public Partial Class WebUserControl1
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Public Property TextOfLabel() As String
    Get
        Return IdOfLabelInUserControl.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        IdOfLabelInUserControl.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```